# JSP Compilation Fails as it is using jdk1.4 though my jboss is using jdk 1.6

Tags: java, jsp, generics, jboss

I am using jboss with jdk1.6... Using Generics heavily in my java code and it works fine. But when I use in jsp; it fails compiling .. Looks like JSP Container is using jdk1.4..

How do I make JSP container also use same JDK as my jboss is using ?

Comment: can you post your piece of code which is not compiling?

Comment: Simple List<String> is not compiling.. which is a feature of jdk1.5

Comment: did you try uninstalling all the jdk's except jdk1.6

Comment: download and try with latest version of `jspApi.jar , serverApi.jar`.

Comment: what jboss version are you using?

Comment: version is jboss4.0.5.GA

Comment: How do you know the JSP container is using jdk 1.4. Where is this JDK 1.4 coming from? Do you have jdk 1.4 installed anywhere on your system?

Comment: Seems that you've got multiple versions of JDK available on your machine.

Comment: Well to be true; I do not know if JSP is using jdk1.4 ; but surely Generics are not supported which made me feel so.

Comment: I do not have any other jdk installed

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem

> The type Collection is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments `<? extends E>`

and the cause was the evil "cryptix-jce-compat.jar" in the classpath.

this evil jar contains an `java/util/List.class` as well as `java/util/ArrayList.class` (and all the others) which hide the relative jre classes.

check if you have a similar situation, maybe [jarscan](https://java.net/projects/jarscan/downloads) can help

Comment: did scanned.. but nothing found.

Answer (score 1):

**Tomcat 5.5.20** uses **Servlet 2.4** and **JSP 2.0** for **J2EE 1.4** platform.
**JDK 1.5** introduces generics, which allows you to abstract over types.

So, in your case if you are upgrading **JDK** you should reinstalled your servlet container. But notice, that **JBoss 4.2.0** and upwards doesn't come bundled with **Tomcat** and called **JBossWeb**. It's independent **Tomcat** code base. So, you can't upgrade **Tomcat** without upgrading **JBoss**.

See Also

- [**Version Of Tomcat In JBossAS**](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS)
- [**JBoss Web**](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb)
- [**Apache Tomcat 5.x vulnerabilities**](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-5.html)

Comment: According to http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.20-copyforpermissions/bin/README.html Tomcat requires JRE5 by default. However, I'm pretty sure that upgrading the container is the most likely solution. JBoss AS 4.0.5 is 8 years old and well out of support.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code from `run.bat` in JBoss 4.0.5 GA bin folder

```
rem Include the JDK javac compiler for JSP pages. The default is for a Sun JDK
rem compatible distribution to which JAVA_HOME points

set JAVAC_JAR=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
```

According to this, if you point the `JAVA_HOME` to JDK 1.6 properly. it should compile the jsps with that version

Comment: Tried this but did not help. Even tried export  JAVAC_JAR="$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar" but same results..Did echo for JAVAC_JAR in run.sh ; gets this value : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/lib/tools.jar which is also ok